# When would ssh -t not be appropriate instead of ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

Using `ssh -t` instead of `ssh` for connections to remote servers has several advantages. For example, I can directly edit a file with vim: `ssh -t host vim foo.txt`, which would fail otherwise.

Are there any circumstances under which allocating a (pseudo)-tty would be a bad thing when using ssh?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When piping the input or getting the input back, which is the typical use of "ssh host command". Control characters could be interpreted by the TTY layer (^S for ex.)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, sometimes you want to make a silent, backgrounded connection, for example when setting up a tunnel (e.g. SOCKS proxy).  In such examples, you want the process to NOT have a tty.

Here's an example of setting up port forwarding from localhost to some remote host...

```
ssh -l username -fNTL 8073:server:873
```

After this has been set up, you can then rsync to localhost, instead of to the remote host, hence effectively, tunneling your rsync via `ssh`...

```
rsync --port=8073 -a me@localhost::myStuff /tmp/myStuff/
```

You'd do this say if rsync going out to `server` was blocked, but `ssh` wasn't.

Comment: Thanks, this was right too, but I voted the other as it was a more serious issue I overlooked.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above...

(1) Different tilda escape handling:

The "~." escape will disconnect you if you have a pty (-t).  For a long-running command, you might want to prevent someone from accidentally halting the process if they type ~.

$ ssh hostname.tomontime.com -t  sleep 60

[type ~. and it disconnects]

Connection to hostname.tomontime.com closed.

$ ssh hostname -T  sleep 60

[I type ~. and it treats it like normal keystrokes, which the sleep command ignores.]

~.

~.

Try the same thing with CTRL-C.  You'll see that with -t you are sending the CTRL-C to the "sleep".  With -T you are sending the CTRL-C to the ssh program running on your machine.  There may be times when this makes a difference (i.e. the program handles INT differently than HUP)

(2) You just want to minimize the pty or network connection activity.

When trying to reboot a machine that is out of ptys you don't want to encourage the system to try to allocate a pty!  This also minimize the network connections that will have to be closed (delaying the reboot).

This will work faster and more reliably:
     ssh -T hostname reboot

This may have problems:
     ssh -t hostname reboot

Answer (score 3):

ssh -t creates a pseudo terminal on the remote machine.
This is useful if you are chaining ssh commands thru multiple servers and want a real terminal on the far side (so you could use 'vi' for example).

You might NOT want '-t' when login scripts behave differently if there is a terminal.
This is bad practice IMHO, but I've seen cases where a login script checks for TTY before
1) setting the prompt, and 2) expanding the path to many interactive applications.

In another instance (mentioned by TomOnTime above), I actually have run into cases where all the TTY (ptys) are used up.  Obviously a mis-configuration, but no need to chew up a resource for a bunch of tunnels and rsyncs.